# Prolog - subtraction in and between trees

Tags: prolog

This is a problem I encountered. How do you subtract values in a binary tree recursively?

```
subtractTree(tree(leaf(4), tree(leaf(2), leaf(1))),S).
  S = 3.
```

For this example, it first subtracts the leaves in each tree before subtracting the values between the trees. So for the first tree, it has the value 4. The second tree, it has the value 1 because 2-1=1. Then it subtracts 4-1 between the trees and the answer is 3.

Answer (score 2):

because your tree structure has arity 2 (as it must be), you can do a very simple visit

```
subtractTree(leaf(N), N).
subtractTree(tree(L, R), S) :-
    subtractTree(L, X),
    subtractTree(R, Y),
    S is X - Y.
```

test:

```
?- subtractTree(tree(leaf(4), tree(leaf(2), leaf(1))),S).
S = 3.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 cases :
Base case : a tree with only leaves

```
subtractTree(tree(leaf(A), leaf(B)),S) :-
         S is A-B.
```

2 intermediate cases, trees with one leaf and a tree as a leaf

```
subtractTree(tree(leaf(A), Tree2),S) :-
    subtractTree(Tree2, S1),
    S is A - S1.

subtractTree(tree(Tree1, leaf(B)),S) :-
    subtractTree(Tree1, S1),
    S is S1 - B.
```

A general case, a tree with leaves which are trees :

```
subtractTree(tree(Tree1, Tree2),S) :-
    subtractTree(Tree1, S1),
    subtractTree(Tree2, S2),
    S is S1 - S2.
```

Comment: +1 for a good explanation. I would note that the O.P. tree structure apparently lacks the ability to represent an empty tree &mdash; and as a result, so does your example.

Comment: @NicholasCarey (and joel76) yes, but what about one-leaf trees?